# Play Framework on Wildfly 8

Tags: playframework, wildfly-8

What is the best option for deploying play framework 2.3.x on Wildfly 8? I know Play Framework is reactive non-blocking IO framework which runs on netty and Wildfly is J2EE based application server. Creating war file of play application and deploying it on wildfly will kill the benefit of play framework so I need most optimized solution for running play application on wildfly.

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin (note that you cannot use websockets with that plugin)